# symfony is validating my form but not dispalying validation messages saying "required"?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

If all the fields in my form are filled correctly, then am able to save form but if some fields are not filled it is not showing validation messages .while binding form it is able to validate using isValid but not showing messages on form.plz help me?
this is my base form

```
abstract class BaseTgSchedulerForm extends BaseFormDoctrine{
public function setup()   
{     
$this->setWidgets(array(

  'id'  => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
  'emp_number'=> new sfWidgetFormInput(array()),
  'task_name'=> new sfWidgetFormInputText(array()),
'curr_execution_date' => new ohrmWidgetDatePicker(array('label'=>'ExecutionDate'),
array('id'=>'curr_execution_date'),array('class'=>'formDateInput')),
  'curr_remind_date'    => new ohrmWidgetDatePicker(array('label'=>'Remind Date'), array('id'=>'curr_remind_date'),array('class'=>'formDateInput')),
        'status_id'           => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
));

$this->setValidators(array(
  'id'                  => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getModelName(), 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
  'emp_number'          => new sfValidatorInteger(array('required'=>true)),
  'task_name'           => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255)),
  'curr_execution_date' => new ohrmDateValidator(array('required'=>true) ),
  'curr_remind_date'    => new ohrmDateValidator(array('required'=>true) ),
        'status_id'           => new sfValidatorInteger(array('required'=>false)),
 ));
$this->setDefault('status_id', 1);
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('tg_scheduler[%s]'); 
$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
$this->setupInheritance();
parent::setup();
 }

 public function getModelName()
 {
return 'TgScheduler';
 }
 }
```

this is my action after submit

```
public function executeSubmit(sfWebRequest $request)
{

    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST));
    $this->form = new TgSchedulerForm();
    $this->processSchedulerForm($request, $this->form);
}
protected function processSchedulerForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
     $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $tg_scheduler = $form->save();
        }
    }
```

code related with rendering form

```
 <form action="<?php echo url_for('scheduler/'.($form->getObject()->isNew() ?      'submit' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?task_id='.$form->getObject()->getTaskId() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
<?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="put" />
<?php endif; ?>
<table class="task-form">
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1"></td><td>
     <!--  &nbsp;<a href="<?php //echo url_for('scheduler/index') ?>">Back to list</a> 
      <?php //if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>
        &nbsp;<?php //echo link_to('Delete', 'scheduler/delete?task_id='.$form->getObject()->getTaskId(), array('method' => 'delete', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?')) ?>
      <?php //endif; ?></td><td>-->
      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
  <?php echo $form ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: a litle bit of code would be nice.

Comment: Especially the part that you use to render the form.

Comment: Did you check the html which is generated when the form has errors? Maybe the error messages are there but you have some css which hides them. Please check your form with errors if the html is produced correctly. Also, in the dev environment, check on the debug bar in the `view` section if the errors which you expect are shown next to the form fields.

Comment: thanks for your repsonse .got my mistake actually i have to put$this->setTemplate('newTask');

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your repsonse .got my mistake actually i have to put

```
 $this->setTemplate('newTask');
```

this line after calling **processSchedulerForm** in **executeSubmit** Action, that is the template used to show that form  sothat i can display validation messages.